# How to pass radio button values and checkbox values through a URL using Powerforms?

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I am having trouble pre filling information from a current application onto a PowerForm. I have managed to transfer almost all of the data from the application fields onto specified fields on the PowerForm template so the applicant can just add sensitive information and sign the form.

The issue is I need to pre fill text boxes with the values of check boxes and radio button from the online application. 
I am aware you can do this through the URL, but i do not know the recipient's identity in advance. Does that matter?

Someone mentioned to do the following

```
powerformURl&role_custometag=Value
```

but what do i set the value for the radio buttons and check boxes.

I do have custom tags on my template and I want the values from the check boxes and radio buttons to pre fill in those custom tags.

if this is confusing i do apologize but I can clarify some more if needed

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that makes sense and actually explains the problem you're having or question you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I must have forgotten to finish the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters on the URL of a Powerform to update various fields in DocuSign.
The complete list of options for these is available here: 
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform

For your case, you need to update the value of a tag which is called EnvelopeField in the URL, so if you do this:

`EnvelopeField_<EnvelopeFieldName>=<value>` as part of the URL, where EnvelopeFieldName is the name of your specific checkbox, you should be able to do that (value will be true/false)